# How to remove rows from a bound Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, delete-row

I have a bound datagridview and i want by clicking a button all rows will be deleted (not from database just from datagridview to add new rows), i tried two different codes but it just delete a half of rows for example if i have 10 it deletes just 5.
this is the first code i tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1 ; i++)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        }
```

And this is the second:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView2.Rows)   
        {
            if (!r.IsNewRow)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(r);
            }
        }
```

Can any one solve this??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How do you bind the datasource? You need to clear the rows from datasource or set the DataSource to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an item from a collection using *RemoveAt*, the indexes of subsequent items goes down by one which is why you're skipping items in your for *int* loop.  So you should either not increment i, or you should go through the list backwards.

Not incrementing:

```
while (dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Going backwards:

```
for (int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Simply do :

```
dataGridView2.Items.Clear();
```